# Loop through Map in Groovy?

Tags: dictionary, groovy

I have a very simple task I am trying to do in Groovy but cannot seem to get it to work. I am just trying to loop through a map object in groovy and print out the key and value but this code does not work.

```
// A simple map
def map = [
        iPhone : 'iWebOS',
        Android: '2.3.3',
        Nokia  : 'Symbian',
        Windows: 'WM8'
]

// Print the values
for (s in map) {
    println s + ": " + map[s]
}
```

I am trying to get the output to look like this:

```
iPhone: iWebOS
Android: 2.3.3
Nokia: Symbian
Windows: WM8
```

Could someone please elaborate on how to do this??

Comment: As you have seen in the answers, the problem is that iterating over a map gives you a collection of "Entries", you were assuming it would give you the keys and you would look up the values.  If you wanted to do it that way, iterate over map.keySet() and the rest will work as you expected.

Comment: It should work if you use `s.key` & `s.value` in your code inside for loop.

Answer (score 372, accepted):

Quite simple with a closure:

```
def map = [
           'iPhone':'iWebOS',
           'Android':'2.3.3',
           'Nokia':'Symbian',
           'Windows':'WM8'
           ]

map.each{ k, v -> println "${k}:${v}" }
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, where is this documented in the Groovy language docs (**I don't think it is!**)? I guess I'm wondering, from a Groovy newbies' perspective, *How did you know this?*

Comment: @smeeb: everything is well documented, take a look here: http://www.groovy-lang.org/groovy-dev-kit.html#_iterating_on_maps

Comment: appreciating that this is a historic post: a for loop and an each closure are not one and the same and there may be times where the latter is preferred over the former.

Answer (score 121):

Alternatively you could use a `for` loop as shown in the [Groovy Docs](http://groovy-lang.org/semantics.html#_looping_structures):

```
def map = ['a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3]
for ( e in map ) {
    print "key = ${e.key}, value = ${e.value}"
}

/*
Result:
key = a, value = 1
key = b, value = 2
key = c, value = 3
*/
```

One benefit of using a `for` loop as opposed to an `each` closure is easier debugging, as you cannot hit a break point inside an `each` closure (when using Netbeans).

Comment: I use GGTS 3.2 and routinely set break points in closures (including "each" closures). The problem is using F6 to step through a closure, as it will go over the whole thing. Technically, you can hit F5 a bunch of times and eventually end up in there, but a break point is faster.

Comment: Updated answer.  I am using Netbeans and its debugging of Groovy/Grails is sub-par.

Comment: Plus you can break out a for loop and not in `.each`.

Comment: @AlexanderSuraphel you are correct that you cannot use `break` to exit `each`, but you can use `return`

Comment: @ubiquibacon no you can't. `return` is analogous to `continue` not `break`.

Comment: The disadvantage of using for loop is that if you have an empty map you will have error like this:
Ambiguous expression could be either a parameterless closure expression or an isolated open code block;
   solution: Add an explicit closure parameter list, e.g. {it -> ...}, or force it to be treated as an open block by giving it a label, e.g. L:{...} @ line 1, column 1.
   {}

Comment: Another reason to use this way: currently you can't use .each in jenkins groovy sandbox `FAILURE: Jenkins exception: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Calling public static java.util.Map org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(java.util.Map,groovy.lang.Closure) on a CPS-transformed closure is not yet supported (JENKINS-26481); encapsulate in a @NonCPS method, or use Java-style loops`

Answer (score 23):

When using the for loop,  the value of s is a Map.Entry element,  meaning that you can get the key from s.key and the value from s.value

Comment: Thanks for explaining *why* the OP's code doesn't work

Answer (score 18):

Another option:

```
def map = ['a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3]
map.each{
  println it.key +" "+ it.value
}
```