# How do I iterate over a nested map?

Tags: groovy

This is my nested map, I want to iterate over each "myMap":

```
def myMaps = [
    "myMap1": [
      "prop1": 'sdfsdfdsf',
      "prop2": 'dsdfsdfs',
      "prop3": 'sdfsdfsdf'
    ],
    "myMap2": [
      "prop1": 'sdfsdfdsf',
      "prop2": 'dsdfsdfs',
      "prop3": 'sdfsdfsdf'
    ]
    "myMap3": [
      "prop1": 'sdfsdfdsf',
      "prop2": 'dsdfsdfs',
      "prop3": 'sdfsdfsdf'
    ]
    "myMap4": [
      "prop1": 'sdfsdfdsf',
      "prop2": 'dsdfsdfs',
      "prop3": 'sdfsdfsdf'
    ]
]
```

I tried this several ways but it's not iterating over the maps, it's still treating it like a single item:

```
myMaps.each() {
    println '========'
    it.dump()
}

for (item in myMaps) {
    println '========'
    println item.key
}
```

### Edit

This was the only way I could manage to do this but I don't understand why. Is this also possible with a more traditional foreach style loop?

```
myMaps.each {
  key, value ->
    println key
    println value
}
```

Comment: Not sure what the question is...  `myMaps.each { it -> println "$it.key -> $it.value" }` works...  is that not what you want?

Comment: I'm confused why this is the only way that works. This top rated question in this post says you can do it with a for loop, but it didn't work for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10037374/loop-through-map-in-groovy

Comment: You can...  this works the same `for (k in myMaps) { println "$k.key -> $k.value" }`

Comment: `k` is an entry, so if you want the key, you need to use `k.key` (and the same for value)

Comment: "I'm confused why this is the only way that works" - It isn't the only way.  There are a lot of ways to iterate over a `Map`.  Are you specifically wanting to know how to do it without using the `each` method for some reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I iterate over a nested map?

One way to do it is with the `each(Closure)` method:

```
def myMaps = [
        "myMap1": [
                "prop1": 'sdfsdfdsf',
                "prop2": 'dsdfsdfs',
                "prop3": 'sdfsdfsdf'
        ],
        "myMap2": [
                "prop1": 'sdfsdfdsf',
                "prop2": 'dsdfsdfs',
                "prop3": 'sdfsdfsdf'
        ],
        "myMap3": [
                "prop1": 'sdfsdfdsf',
                "prop2": 'dsdfsdfs',
                "prop3": 'sdfsdfsdf'
        ],
        "myMap4": [
                "prop1": 'sdfsdfdsf',
                "prop2": 'dsdfsdfs',
                "prop3": 'sdfsdfsdf'
        ]
]

myMaps.each { outerKey, outerValue ->
    println "${outerKey}:"
    outerValue.each { innerKey, innerValue ->
        println "\t${innerKey} -> ${innerValue}"
    }
}
```

Output:

```
myMap1:
    prop1 -> sdfsdfdsf
    prop2 -> dsdfsdfs
    prop3 -> sdfsdfsdf
myMap2:
    prop1 -> sdfsdfdsf
    prop2 -> dsdfsdfs
    prop3 -> sdfsdfsdf
myMap3:
    prop1 -> sdfsdfdsf
    prop2 -> dsdfsdfs
    prop3 -> sdfsdfsdf
myMap4:
    prop1 -> sdfsdfdsf
    prop2 -> dsdfsdfs
    prop3 -> sdfsdfsdf
```

**EDIT:**

The question was edited to add the following:

> Is this also possible with a more traditional foreach style loop?

If you want to use a `for` loop, there are a number of ways to do that.  One is shown here:

```
    for(Map.Entry outerEntry : myMaps) {
        println "${outerEntry.key}"
        for(Map.Entry innerEntry: outerEntry.value) {
            println "\t${innerEntry.key} -> ${innerEntry.value}"
        }
    }
```